# MySQL update query is updating all fields except date (using PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple update query for when someone subscribes to my web app, updating the details of their license.

Recently I made some minor changes to this and it has stopped working (I presume these are linked, but haven't actually managed to prove this) - I've tried reversing whatever I did but seems to be to no avail.

For some reason, the update runs successfully and all fields update, except the `expiry` field.

I write my sql query into a log file and I've copied this into phpmyadmin command line and it works exactly as expected.

[Result is:

```
UPDATE License 
   SET type='Full'
     , payer_id = 'XXXXXXX'
     , gross = 'XXXX'
     , payer_email = 'XXXXXXX' 
     , license_start = '2019-08-21 14:46:17'
     , expiry = '2019-09-21'
     , product = 'MON'
     , stripe_id = 'XXXXXX' 
 WHERE user_id = XXX
```

which seems fine to me

I've adapted the format, apostrophes, I've even just put a date in like '2019-12-10' and it still won't update via the mysqli query. I've also tried `expiry` = $start, which requires truncation, but should work... still just doesn't update that field.

```php
$expiry = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+$couponmonths months", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$expiryts))));
$start = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "UPDATE `$license_table` SET `type`='Full', `payer_id`='$subid', `gross`='$price', `payer_email`='$email', `license_start`='$start', `expiry` = '$expiry', `product`='$product_name', `stripe_id`='$stripeid' WHERE `user_id`=$userid";
    }
...
if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql) === TRUE) {...}
```

Comment: What is the type of `expiry` column in your database?

Comment: The type is DATE

Comment: Basic debugging technique: `$sql = "..."; var_dump($sql); exit;`.

Comment: Why do you have two statements in one SQL string? I don't see that in your PHP code. And it shouldn't work at all with `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Yes. I removed second statement and changed mysqli_multi_query to mysqli_query in an attempt to remove some of the noise around my question. All elements of the both queries are successfully completing except the expiry field in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks those of you that tried to help. I've fixed this now by literally creating a new column called `expiry_date` instead of `expiry`, copying the data across to the new column, and updating all references.

Feel like I haven't solved what went wrong, but I have at least got it working again. It felt like the column had decided to to accept updates via PHP - not sure this is even possible???

I decided to try this course of action when I sent a query saying only to update this column and it still didn't work... madness!

Would love to hear an explanation if there is one, but just happy to have it working for now.